# How to convert varchar to decimal so that it would be seen as number in Excel

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a column with data type `decimal (18,2)`.
I use it in my view which is imported by Excel.
What I'm trying to do is to cast it as numeric so that it would by seen in Excel as number.
I get this error:

> error converting data type varchar to numeric.

Here's my code:

```
cast(replace(isnull([wartosc],''),'.',',') AS numeric(18,2)) AS wartosc
```

Comment: What's the data in `wartosc`? What rdbms are you working with (Sybase or SQL Server) ? what version?

Comment: You can't cast an empty string to `numeric` in SQL Server. Remove the `isnull` to get `null` back from the cast if `wartosc` is null

Comment: I use SQL Server 2012, here's example data in wartosc column: 1035514.61

Comment: Why are you replacing the `.` with `,`? what's the result of `SELECT @@LANGUAGE` in your system?

Comment: [decimal and numeric](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/decimal-and-numeric-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) are synonyms in SQL server - If the source data type is actually decimal than you don't need to cast at all...

Comment: Don't replace "." with "," .it will make column as string. That's why you are getting conversion error varchar to numeric.

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want to convert characters in the column use try_cast function in sql server it will automatically ignore null and characters and give them null if that value cannot be converted , The query is not failing either.

```
select try_cast(replace(isnull([wartosc],''),'.',',') AS numeric(18,2)) AS wartosc
```